# EditBox Text Alignment using Cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: c++, textbox, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using CCEditBox  in the latest cocos2d-x 3.2 as textBox for user input.
now , i want to align text which i am typing in Textbox area , but it's always stays left align. i want to set it in the Center of my textBox.

I tried one Function named : **setLabelAnchorPoint** but it's not giving any effect to my label alignment. please help.

```
 cocos2d::extension::Scale9Sprite *Playername_bgtemp =    cocos2d::extension::Scale9Sprite::create("Name_bg.png");
 auto  _editName = EditBox::create(Size(1000,164), Playername_bgtemp);

 Point absolutePosition = Point(ReferenceFrameSprite->getContentSize().width/2,4*ReferenceFrameSprite->getContentSize().height*0.20);

_editName->setPosition(absolutePosition);
_editName->setFontName("fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Cond_0.ttf");
_editName->setFontColor(Color3B::WHITE);
_editName->setLabelAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.0f,0.0f));
_editName->setPlaceHolder(" Name ");
_editName->setPlaceholderFontColor(Color3B::WHITE);
_editName->setPlaceholderFontName("fonts/HelveticaLTStd-Cond_0.ttf");
_editName->setMaxLength(10);
_editName->setReturnType(EditBox::KeyboardReturnType::DONE);
_editName->setFontSize(BgContentFontSize);
_editName->setDelegate(this);
bgFrameSprite->addChild(_editName,PopUpTag);
```

Comment: i came to know about this post , it seems textfiled lacking  text alignment (left, right, center) & other text customization functionalities and so they are going to merge it with UI according to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846780/textfield-in-cocos2d-x-3-0-with-background-image-text-alignment-and-colored-sha

Answer (score 0):

I did the trick with a text Label in the same position than the Editbox. I keep the Editbox with an empty string.

When start editing the edit box:

- Hide the label.
- Set the Editbox text with the label content.

When end editing the Editbox:

- Set label text to Editbox content.
- Show the label.
- Set Editbox text to an empty string.